# Solve the Euler's equation $x^2y^{\prime \prime}+3xy^{\prime}+10y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the Euler's equation $$x^2y^{\prime \prime}+3xy^{\prime}+10y=0$$ For $x>0$, I use the transformation $z=ln x$ to get a homogenous equation with constant coefficient and then I manage to solve it. But for $x \leq 0$, I have no idea what transformation to use.

Comment: What is the domain of the solution?  Is it the whole real line?

Comment: not stated in question. So I think it should be the whole line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\lt 0$, essentially the same procedure will work, with $y=\ln(|x|)$.

Comment: but my solution obtained is not continuous at $x=0$. is it still okay ?

Comment: I think it is, there is a problem transferring information from $x\gt 0$ to $x\lt 0$. For a much simpler analogue, consider $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}=1$, that is, the integral of $1/x^2$. The correct general solution is $y=-\frac{1}{x}+C_1$ for positive $x$, $-\frac{1}{x}+C_2$ for negative $x$, with $C_1$ not necessarily equal to $C_2$.

Comment: but then in the example given by you, when divided by $x^2$, we alreadu assume $x \neq 0$ and in fact, $x=0$ is not a solution to the equation.

Comment: It was an analogy. Certainly in your case $y=0$ is a solution, though I think it does not come directly from the general solution process.